# .htaccess RewriteRule gives right link but also a 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm hosting different sites

```
http://example.nl/example.nl/_sites/byos/
http://example.nl/example.nl/_sites/eggbot/
http://example.nl/example.nl/_sites/hslab/
http://example.nl/example.nl/_sites/prolactin/
```

And yes there is a folder that has the same name as the domain, there is a reason for that.

And I want the links to become:

```
http://example.nl/byos/
http://example.nl/eggbot/
http://example.nl/hslab/
http://example.nl/prolactin/
```

This is one of the many attempts:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)example.nl/_sites
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.nl/_sites/$1 [L]
```

And this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^example.nl/_sites/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

The last one brings me close, it changes the address in what I want it to be, but it also results in a 404 now.
I also tried it with renaming the example.nl folder so it is not the same as the domain name but the problem seems to be the same.

In case it is important for later, I also have folders with files here:

```
http://example.nl/example.nl/_misc/
http://example.nl/example.nl/_plugins/
```

But I don't care if those get renamed, since they won't appear in the url bar, unless the user goes directly to one of those files, but I don't care about that.

So how can I omit the `example.nl/_sites/` part and still have the website working?

I have seen the similar questions on SO, but for me it looks like Chinese in another dialect.

---- edit:
using the following of the answer from anubhava:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}::%{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:www\.)?([^:]+)::GET\s/+\1/_sites/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/?$ %1/_sites%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

I don't get a 404 anymore.
But this files for example:

`http://hslab.nl/hslab.nl/_misc/bna.js`

It tries to load it as:

`http://hslab.nl/_misc/bna.js`

Which fails. In the code it was targeted as:

`src="../../_misc/bna.js"`

In case it helps here is a screenshot of the **folder** `hslab.nl`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without hardcoding host name, you may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}::%{THE_REQUEST} ^(?:www\.)?([^:]+)::GET\s/+\1/_sites/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/?$ %1/_sites%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the OP at the bottom with more info.

Comment: Problem is not the rules but use of `src="../../_misc/bna.js"`. It should be `src="_misc/bna.js"`

Comment: damn, that will break the site if no RewriteRule is applied :(

Comment: You either want a pretty URL or old URL, you have to decide. However if you want `src=` to work for both the cases then use absolute URL like `src="/example.nl/_misc/bna.js"`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Fair warning I have written this in mobile so yet to test it should work IMHO will test it in sometime too. Also since you mentioned there could be multiple domains so I have specifically put a condition to check if it's example.nl here in case you want to rewrite request for any domain then we could omit that condition too.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ %{HTTP_HOST}/_sites/$1 [L]
```

Note: in case you directories/folders are not necessarily starting with alphabets and could be anything  then change regex in above from `^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$` TO `^([.*])/?$`

Comment: Hi, thanks helping, so far it does nothing.

Comment: @clankill3r, could you please do let me know which url you are hitting and what you are seeing in logs or browser? So that I will get better understanding of it, thank you.

Comment: I hit, http://hslab.nl/hslab.nl/_sites/prolactin/ and it shows up but the link is unchanged. The error log is empty, the other log looks like this: https://pastebin.pl/view/86b37762
(last 100 lines, and I spammed loading the site a few times)

Comment: @clankill3r, ohh so you want to hit  url with _sites in it `http://example.nl/example.nl/_sites/byos/
` on browser and it get it served by non _sites url in backend? eg from `http://example.nl/byos/` because I understood it vice versa :) kindly confirm once and I will edit my rules then.

Comment: No, I think you understood it right the first time. There is an image in the OP now of the folder.

Comment: @clankill3r, oh ok. You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.